# jQuery autocomplete value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm writing app in rails and I am using twitter-typeahead-rails for typeahead and searchkick for search. I wrote code in js to automatically search after change in input. When I'm taking value of input after change it takes value with hint of typeahead however I want to take value without that hint.

```
var numbers;
numbers = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: "/local/autocomplete"
});

numbers.initialize();

$(document).ready(function() {
// instantiate the typeahead UI
    $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: numbers.ttAdapter()
    });
    $('.typeahead').on('input', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/local/search',
            data: {local: $('.typeahead').val()}
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Which version of twitter typeahead plugin are you using?

Comment: twitter-typeahead-rails 0.11.1

Comment: also, why not take the value from the selected suggestion?

Comment: I want to give a user hints that he can choose from, however searchkick should look for that what he is actually typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about typeahead rails. If it works the same as the [original typeahead plugin](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md) then you can disable the hint via option `hint: false`

If you don't want to disable the hint: typeahead creates a seperate input for the hint, by default:

`.tt-hint` contains the hint

`.tt-input` contains the user input

So, in your script get the value from `.tt-input`

Comment: Cheers. Just in case you want to use a more specific selector you can include the original input class. In your case that would be .typeahead.tt-input